# Massive log files on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, log, logging, syslog

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04. For some reason I have massive log files.

For example: kern.log is 10.5 GB big and syslog is 152 MB.

I already tried rotating them, but I wanna know what's making them so big.

This is the outout of `tail kern.log`:

```
Jun 17 17:23:24 Master NetworkManager[782]: <info>  [1466195004.4140] device (wlxd85d4c99fb61): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Jun 17 17:23:24 Master NetworkManager[782]: <info>  [1466195004.4142] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL   
Jun 17 17:23:24 Master NetworkManager[782]: <info>  [1466195004.4839] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL  
Jun 17 17:23:24 Master NetworkManager[782]: <info>  [1466195004.4841] policy: set 'dlink-323' (wlxd85d4c99fb61) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jun 17 17:23:24 Master NetworkManager[782]: <info>  [1466195004.4842] DNS: starting dnsmasq...   
Jun 17 17:23:24 Master NetworkManager[782]: <warn>  [1466195004.5002] dnsmasq[0x215ef40]: dnsmasq not found on the bus. The nameserver update will be sent when dnsmasq appears   
Jun 17 17:23:24 Master NetworkManager[782]: <info>  [1466195004.5003] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf   
Jun 17 17:23:24 Master NetworkManager[782]: <info>  [1466195004.6916] device (wlxd85d4c99fb61): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jun 17 17:23:24 Master NetworkManager[782]: <info>  [1466195004.7009] dnsmasq[0x215ef40]: dnsmasq appeared as :1.69
Jun 17 17:23:24 Master NetworkManager[782]: <info>  [1466195004.7011] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
```

"Master" is the name of my computer, "dlink-323" the name of the wifi network I'm connected to.

What's going on here?

I don't have any Firewall, special DNS setup or anything. Just a regular WiFi connection. No firewall on the hotspot either.

This is the output of `tail syslog`:

```
Jun 17 17:36:56 Master dbus[721]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Jun 17 17:36:56 Master systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jun 17 17:36:56 Master dbus[721]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jun 17 17:36:56 Master systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jun 17 17:38:32 Master dbus[721]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Jun 17 17:38:32 Master systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jun 17 17:38:32 Master dbus[721]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jun 17 17:38:32 Master systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jun 17 17:38:35 Master gnome-session[1154]: Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process "net" (No such file or directory)
Jun 17 17:46:45 Master org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[1042]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:1497): WARNING **: Unable to get info on application://gnome-terminal-server.desktop
```

Is Ubuntu logging all network traffic? If that's the case, how can I stop it?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what causes NetworkManager to log so many lines, and you certainly should look into this, but you can control that by inserting a `[logging]` section in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` followed by `level=warn`. Then, restart NetworkManager. This will avoid lines that are merely "<info>".

Comment: @Jos Thanks! I did that. Don't know what else to do!